# c# public const A first

Tags: c#

```
public const A first;
public const B second;
```

These two lines give error, how can i modify this.

```
public class TwoTuple<A,B>
{
    public const A first;
    public const B second;

    public TwoTuple(A  a,B b)
    {
        first=a;
        second=b;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ")"+first+", " +second+")";
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: There is already `Tuple<T1, T2>` class available in .NET.

Comment: The answer is: you're not using the language correctly. Simple research on `"C# const"` will explain why what you've written makes no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this to:

```
public readonly A first;
public readonly B second;
```

Consts cannot be set, readonly variables can be set in the constructor.

Comment: Are you assuming `A` and `B` are types?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - I think you have to... This is the only valid answer since their value is unknown at compile time (presumably)

Comment: Okay, after the edits I think I see what he's doing... `A` and `B` are *generic type parameters*.

Comment: Yes I am assuming that.

Answer (score 6):

The value of a `const` variable has to be known at compile time. In other words, you have to assign something to that variable when you declare it, like `const string name = "sharp.m";`

More on C# const: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b(v=vs.90).aspx

**Edit**
Actually, you can't use const with your type `A` or `B` at all. For a variable to be declared `const`, it has to be either a string, null or a value type (e.g., int). Like others have stated, you should use `readonly` instead.

Comment: I updated my example. I didn't realize at first that he was using his own custom type.